# Export SQL database to remote server error 1064

Tags: sql, web, joomla, phpmyadmin

I have developed a Joomla site locally and am in the process of transferring it to a remote server, but I can't seem to get the SQL database imported correctly. No matter which option I choose during the exporting from PhpMyAdmin, I get this error.

[image]

The issue looks to be with the ';' in the 'display: none;' statement but I'm not sure a) why it's there or b) how to fix it. The entire exported file doesn't look quite right to me, honestly. I'm not real good with SQL, but to me, the export file looks more like HTML and less like SQL. I guess I expected more traditional looking SQL statements, so that got me to wondering if the file created during the export is even valid.

I've put the resulting export file up on Drive if that helps. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B48CjF6vEPyaSEtGNFpydVd2OGc/view?usp=sharing

Thanks so much in advance! I'm completely stuck on this.

Answer (score 0):

This is not SQL it is an error message.  For example I found this text in the HTML:

**Notice** in .\export.php#220
 Undefined index: output_format

**Backtrace**

**Notice** in .\export.php#234
 Undefined index: compression

**Backtrace**

**Notice** in .\export.php#347
 Undefined variable: filename_template

**Backtrace**

**Notice** in .\export.php#423
 Undefined index: sql_structure_or_data

**Backtrace**

**Notice** in .\libraries\export.lib.php#613
 Undefined index: sql_structure_or_data

**Backtrace**

etc

Comment: Thanks. It didn't look right to me either. I'm just not sure how to go about getting a valid export from PhpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I had a look at your error image and your sql file. What I can say is the file that you're trying to import has special characters like (`, ", ..etc.).

First of all, you need to export them correctly. A tool like MySQL workbench can easily export the data for you and when you import there is less problem. I tried with my MySQL Workbench and imported the whole file that you have uploaded as insert record with escape characters, and it is successful for a single record.

**NOTE:**

I am not able to show the whole insert statement with your full text as there is size limit for total characters in SO. Hope you get my drift which is to use proper escape character like below

---

```
INSERT INTO `abc` VALUES (1,'<!DOCTYPE HTML><html lang=\'en\' dir=\'ltr\' class=\'chrome chrome51\'><head><meta charset=\"utf-8\" /><meta name=\"robots\" content=\"noindex,nofollow\" /><meta http-equiv=\"X-UA-Compatible\" content=\"IE=Edge\"><style id=\"cfs-style\">html{display: none;}</style><link rel=\"icon\" href=\"favicon.ico\" type=\"image/x-icon\" /><link rel=\"shortcut icon\" href=\"favicon.ico\" type=\"image/x-icon\" /><link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"./themes/pmahomme/jquery/jquery-ui-1.11.2.css\" /><link rel=\"stylesheet\" ...\n</span></th><td><input type=\"number\" name=\"NavigationTreeTableLevel\" id=\"NavigationTreeTableLevel\" value=\"1\" /><a');
```

**UPDATE:**

1. Link to download MySQL Workbench
   https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/
2. How to use MySQL Workbench for export
   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-admin-export-import-management.html
3. Youtube demo on how to export. 
   Note: The user is from India, you may have problem understanding his English but give it a try as the video is informative should be judged based on its content.
   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OcoIqgnHG54

Comment: I have no idea how to use MySQL workbench. Could you tell me how I would go about exporting my locally hosted Joomla database via MySWL workbench?

Comment: Please read my update on the material needed to accomplish the export task.